# How do I programmatically access GCS hosted files from GAE Java8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a Java8 GAE project with the GAE provisioned GCS bucket. I have a set of files stored in a "subdirectory" in GCS. I can access these files using `gsutil` as follows:

```
gsutil cp gs://gae-java8-project.appspot.com/files/109.avro .
```

However, I can't get these files using `com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsService`. The error I see in the StackDriver logs is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not find: GcsFilename(gae-java8-project.appspot.com, /files/109.avro)
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
int x = ...
GcsFilename fileName =
        new GcsFilename(
            "gae-java8-project.appspot.com", 
            String.format("/files/%d.avro", x));
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Halp?

Comment: Have you checked the Bucket permission?

Comment: According to the documentation, "By default, when you create a bucket for your project, your app has all the permissions required to read and write to it."

Comment: And I take that back. Adding read permission to the GAE App account has changed the error trace. #winning

Comment: Basically, you'll have to change the Bucket and Object permission.